# JAXB Unmarshalling for multiple objects

Tags: java

How to create JAXBContext with two different objects like Employee, Customer.
Please suggest me the options.

Answer (score 0):

That should be fairly easy:

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customer.class, Employee.class);
```